# Different search path behavior for functions in YugabyteDB compared to PostgreSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm investigating switching from PostgreSQL to YSQL and I'm not able to set up our Rails application against YSQL running locally.

I'm trying to import a postgresql dump but I'm getting different behavior with search paths. If I run the following on Postgresql (version 14.1 in my case) it works fine:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto WITH SCHEMA public;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SELECT gen_random_uuid(); #=>  9e7b2d3f-c76f-4f7c-bc31-33451995afdb
```

With ysqlsh (11.2-YB-2.13.0.0-b0) I get this however:

```
ERROR: function gen_random_uuid() does not exist
```

This means I can't import my Rails structure.sql schema because the pg dump it does sets the search path to ''. Then this fails:

```
CREATE TABLE public.data (id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in PostgreSQL 14 because `gen_random_uuid()` is part of the core since PG13, and then not needed to see the functions created by the extensions in the `public` schema.
The current YugabyteDB version is compatible with PG11 where I guess the behavior is the same.